# Question about Runnable Interface in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

one way to implement a thread is like this:

```
  Runnable r1 = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
          // my code here
    }
  };  

  Thread thread1 = new Thread(r1);
  thread1.start();
```

Now if i am to stick to this simple method, is there anyway to pass a value inside the run block from outside of this thread. For example my code inside run contains a logic which require output stream from a process which it will use when called.

How can i pass this process stream object to this run block.

I know there are other methods like implementing runnable or extenting thread, but can you tell me how to accomplish this using the above method.

Comment: outside your Runnable you may want to declare a *final AtomicReference<OutputStream> ref = new AtomicReference<OutputStream>* and later on do a *ref.set( ...)*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a local `final` variable:

```
final OutputStream stream = /* code that creates/obtains an OutputStream */

Runnable r1 = new Runnable() { 
  public void run() {
      // code that uses stream here
  }
};  

Thread thread1 = new Thread(r1);
thread1.start();
```

`final` variables are visible to anonymous inner classes, like your `Runnable` above.

If your Runnable becomes sufficiently complicated then you should consider making it into a named class. At that point constructor arguments are generally the best mechanism for passing parameters.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, I got it.  Thanks!!
Btw is there some possibility to call multiple instances of the same thread with different parameters passed to it without having to use any constructor?

Comment: @David: yes. A `final` variable's value is only "fixed" for that scope. If you have a `final` variable declared in a loop you can initialize it with a different value on each iteration. Likewise, if it's declared in a helper method it can be initialized with a different value on each invocation of that helper method.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you do not have the `OutputStream` handy when starting the thread, but will be obtaining it later.  **If you already have the stream object reference, you should instead use Laurence's example.**

---

You could use some wrapper class, like so:

```
// This is a very simplified example; use getters and setters instead.
class OutputStreamWrapper {
    public OutputStream outputStream;
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
final OutputStreamWrapper wrapper = new OutputStreamWrapper();

Runnable r1 = new Runnable() { 
  public void run() {
    // use wrapper.outputStream in here when appropriate
  }
};  

Thread thread1 = new Thread(r1);
thread1.start();
```

Then you would hand the object referenced by the `wrapper` variable to some other method or class, who would in turn set the `outputStream` property to pass the stream to the thread code.

Note that this is kind of a hack; implementing `Runnable` on another class and giving it such a field would be preferable.

Comment: Actually i want to implement this strictly in a single class. I know it sounds strange but in my compiled code, i need only one class. This is the problem i have.

Comment: @David: So?  Make the wrapper an inner class.  `new Runnable()` is *already* creating an inner class; the compiler is just doing it for you.  (If this is why you don't want to create a new class implementing `Runnable`, then just make that runnable an inner class too.  Any way you look at it, there will be an inner class.  The only question is whether you write it or the compiler does.)

Comment: @David, your idea of implementation works for simple cases. cdhowie is right, if you look at your compiled files you will have additional class files for each Runnable interface, so if that is limiting you from going for external class implementation, you better rethink.

Comment: if you're only using your 'Wrapper' as a way to get the reference to the OutputStream, then it's much better (and simpler and less *multi-threading-reinventing-the-wheel-error-prone*) to simply use a  *final AtomicReference<OutputStream> ref = new AtomicReference<OutputStream>*.

Comment: @SpoonBender: Noted.  If the references exchanged need to later be expanded beyond just one OutputStream, having a dedicated class would make adding more members more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. From inside the `run` method you can access all variables in the enclosing method that have the `final` qualifier.

```
public void demo() {
  final int accessible = 123;
  int notAccessible = 456;
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println(accessible);
    }
  }.start());
}
```

Comment: final is a limiting factor here. It might be the case that outputStream keep changing and he might have to call it many times with diff values, so final won't suffice.
Passing arguments through constructor is what he should implement.